# @types/leaflet not compile at ionic transpile

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, types, ionic2, leaflet

I Have a problem when I try to compile my ionic ts code.

at the compilation of the code at the `transpile` section it's failed beacuse

> [02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/geojson/index.d.ts, line: 142
>               ',' expected.

```
 L141:  id?: string | number;
 L143:   * Properties associated with this feature.
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/geojson/index.d.ts, line: 163
            ',' expected.

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/geojson/index.d.ts, line: 164
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 605
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
                              nds InternalPolyline {
 L606:          constructor(latlngs: LatLngExpression[], options?: PolylineOptions);
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 607
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L606:          constructor(latlngs: LatLngExpression[], options?: PolylineOptions);
 L607:          toGeoJSON(): GeoJSONFeature<GeoJSONPolygon | GeoJSONMultiPolygon>;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 614
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
                               ends Polygon {
 L615:          constructor(latLngBounds: LatLngBoundsExpression, options?: PolylineOptions);
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 616
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L615:      constructor(latLngBounds: LatLngBoundsExpression, options?: PolylineOptions);
   16:      setBounds(latLngBounds: LatLngBoundsExpression): this;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 634
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L633:      options: CircleMarkerOptions;
 L634:      feature?: GeoJSONFeature<GeoJSONPoint>;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 641
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L640:  constructor(latlng: LatLngExpression, options?: CircleMarkerOptions);
 L641:  constructor(latlng: LatLngExpression, radius: number, options?: CircleMarkerOptions); // deprecated!
 L642:  getBounds(): LatLngBounds;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 689
            Generic type 'FeatureCollection' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L690:           * Removes the layer with the given internal ID or the given layer from the group.
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 689
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L690:           * Removes the layer with the given internal ID or the given layer from the group.
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 743
            Generic type 'FeatureCollection' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L742:      function layerGroup(layers: Layer[]): LayerGroup;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 743
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L742:      function layerGroup(layers: Layer[]): LayerGroup;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 783
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L782:  * feature and its LatLng.
 L784:  * The default is to spawn a default Marker:
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 799
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

````
 L798:  * The default value is to not override any defaults:
 L800:  * ```
````

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 825
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L826:  * function (geoJsonFeature) {
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 838
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L837:          coordsToLatLng?(coords: [number, number] | [number, number, number]): LatLng; // check if LatLng has an altitude property
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 856
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L855:          static coordsToLatLng(coords: [number, number] | [number, number, number]): LatLng;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 890
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L889:          addData(data: GeoJSONGeoJsonObject): Layer;
```

[02:17:56]  typescript: ...project/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index.d.ts, line: 890
            Generic type 'Feature' requires 3 type argument(s).

```
 L889:          addData(data: GeoJSONGeoJsonObject): Layer;
```

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at BuildError.Error (native)
    at new BuildError (project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:137:20
    at transpileWorker (project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:103:12)
    at Object.transpile (project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:61:12)
    at buildProject (project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:97:78)
    at project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:47:16

anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `package.json` the `"@types/leaflet": "1.5.9"` include newer version of `"@types/geojson"`,

so I needed just to include the `"@types/geojson"` myself and set a specific version like this: `"@types/geojson": "1.0.5"`.